# Loop through cells in a google sheet and create a string with a certain format

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

With @Tanaike suggestion, I rewrote my question to make this clearer.

I would like to process a google sheet and create a string of a certain value. For example here is a made-up data set,
[image]

There are 3 rows in the data set above, I would like to create a text string with content as described below:

[image]

Here is the end result:
[image]

Here is a google sheet [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l52JepSCGdyy6l0oSGg_T4dSZtPfP0EzVGdJKvUF9w4/edit?usp=sharing) for all of the images above.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your question, can you provide the sample input and output values you expect?

Comment: I have rewritten the question with a sample input and output values. Could you take another look @Tanaike ?

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. I noticed that an answer has already been posted. I think that the answerer might be thinking of the modified script. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer.

Comment: @Tanaike, thanks for letting me know. I appreciate you even more with last sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I did the first three strings.  You can complete the rest yourself.

```
function stupidStrings() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  //const rg=sh.getRange("A1:T4");
  const rg=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn);//perhaps this is the modification you are looking for as this will get all of the rows of data
  const vA=rg.getValues();
  var html="";
  html+=Utilities.formatString('<br />AIR***[%s][%s][%s]*99*****\\',vA[1][0],vA[1][1],vA[1][2]);
  html+=Utilities.formatString('<br />PAT*[%s]*[%s]****\\',vA[1][3],vA[1][5]);                             
  html+=Utilities.formatString('<br />PRE*[%s][%s][%s]*[%s]**\\',vA[1][12],vA[1][13],vA[1][7],vA[1][19]);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html), 'Stupid Strings')
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I need this to dynamically change with the number of rows of the data. I have rewritten the question to simplify things a bit. Could you take another look?

Comment: I used the loop and it worked dynamically. Thank you very much for you help!